# I want to insert a checkbox inside a accordion header in my Application (AIR).Can any one of you please help it out?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript, flex3

In my application i want checkbox on the accordion ,so is it possiable to set checkbox ? if it is possiable How can i identified child ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 width="100%" height="100%">
      <mx:Accordion>
                <mx:headerRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                                <mx:CheckBox label="myCkb"
/>
                        </mx:Component>
                </mx:headerRenderer>
                <mx:Panel title="Content1" label="P1" width="200"
height="200" />
                <mx:Panel title="Content2" label="P2" width="200"
height="200" />
                <mx:Panel title="Content3" label="P3" width="200"
height="200" />
        </mx:Accordion>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you meen by "insert a checkbox inside a accordion header". Add a CheckBox icon? Add a CheckBox funcionality?

Probably you need new component like [this](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2007/03/29/accordion-with-icons/) - "Accordion with Icons". Look how it's done. You must create your own CheckBox logic or use CheckBox component instead of a icon.

Comment: CheckBox funcionality (if i select that checkbox within accordion header child also select )
is it possiable to create checkbox component on the accordion header

Comment: Only if you write your own accordion. It's not so hard. Then you will add events listeners for MouseEvent to part of accordion header under CheckBox component - not on main container of accordion header. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to just change the arrow, then you can make an itemRenderer for the Accordion's header, and place it inside Accordion.headerRenderer

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/24/creating-a-simple-flex-accordion-inline-header-renderer/